# Subscribing a knockout observable to a custom Jquery event with FuelUX tree

Tags: knockout.js, fuelux

I am trying to find out the best way of how to subscribe an custom jQuery event to a Knockout 3.2 view model.

I am using the FuelUX tree control and I would like to push the selected object to my view model observable whenever someone selects a tree item.

The FuelUx control has a built in jQuery event to handle the click and return to a function the selected jQuery data object that is attached to the DOM element. The following is basic code

```
$('#myTree').on('selected.fu.tree', function (evt, data) {

    var selectedArray = $('#myTree').tree('selectedItems'); //fuelux custom event
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(selectedArray, function (bnd) {
        if (bnd) {
             self.linked_documents.push(new DocFile(bnd.dataAttributes.document));
        }
    });
});
```

I have looked at the following and maybe this is the right approach. However any suggestions/recommendations would be appreciated.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the "event" term, the `event` binding is mostly useful for binding to DOM events. Instead, you could use a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to hook up a piece of the view to a UI plugin.

For example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers["fuelEX"] = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).on('selected.fu.tree', function (evt, data) {
      // Modify your view model here in response to the plugin's event
      var observable = valueAccessor();
      observable(observable() + 1);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
  }

};

ko.applyBindings({ 
  counter: ko.observable(1),
  simulateFuelEXEvent: function() { console.log('hai'); $("#fuel").trigger("selected.fu.tree"); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="fuel" data-bind="fuelEX: counter"></div>
<p>Counter value: <span data-bind="text: counter"></span></p>
<p><button data-bind="click: simulateFuelEXEvent">Simulate event</button></p>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great!!

for future people using the FuelUx tree control. I had to databind to the following

<ul class="tree" role="tree" id="myTree" data-bind="fuelEXSelected: linked_documents">